# Restricting IOS app in app store to certain devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm not an iOS developer but I'm faced with the need to publish our application to App Store. Sorry if it the questions sounds stupid:)

We need to make a test flight, just to show the app to our customer. The issue is that we need to do it not through Fabric and etc but through App Store, that's crucial.

Is there an opportunity to restrict the app to certain devices by UDID since the app is not ready? Thank you!

**UPDATE** I need to publish to App Store, not though Fabric or Test Flight and etc. I understand it should not be done this way but I have such requirements

Comment: If you are submitting to TestFlight, then you can restrict who can access your beta. If you submit to the AppStore, you cannot really restrict your app in that way. If you do not want to submit to TestFlight then you could create an `ad-hoc` build which would allow you to restrict by UUID.

Comment: @Andrew you mean I can publish an app to app store using ad-hoc build that will restrict the app to the devices attached to the provisioning profile?

Comment: No you cannot publish to the AppStore with an ad-hoc profile. You can only publish to the AppStore with a AppStore profile. The ad-hoc profile is only meant for in-house testing allowing you to limit which devices that receive it. You cannot upload an ad-hoc profile to the AppStore or to TestFlight. If you publish to the AppStore then it will be available for anyone to download.

Comment: @Andrew ok, now I see. So the answer is actually no, it is not possible. Sad :C thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot distribute through app store and target some specific device. 
If you publish on the app store then the app becomes visible to all.

If you would like to make some kind of restriction than make a login screen through which you open up the rest of the app, and give the credentials to your specific customer.

Answer (score 2):

try using  diawi.com
Diawi is a tool for developers to deploy Development and In-house applications directly to the devices

Answer (score 1):

Using Test Flight you can share the app-store version to your customer based on his appleId

From  https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#before-you-submit

> 2.2 Beta Testing
>   Demos, betas, and trial versions of your app don’t belong on the App Store – use TestFlight instead. Any app submitted for beta
>   distribution via TestFlight should be intended for public distribution
>   and should comply with the App Review Guidelines. Note, however, that
>   apps using TestFlight cannot be distributed to testers in exchange for
>   compensation of any kind, including as a reward for crowd-sourced
>   funding. Significant updates to your beta build should be submitted to
>   TestFlight App Review before being distributed to your testers. To
>   learn more, visit the TestFlight Beta Testing.

Comment: we're using Fabric but I need to publish the app to app store. Will he be able to download the app from app store?

Comment: Not from the AppStore, but via Apple's app TestFlight. It will be the exact build from the store.

Comment: that's the issue actually.. but thanks anyway, I understand that this is how things should be done

Answer (score 0):

You can publish to the App Store using Apple's B2B program, which will allow you to restrict sales to specific B2B customers of yours.

See: https://developer.apple.com/business/custom-apps/